# What replace this in a Static Method?

Tags: list

I'm studying Java, i have to create a Static equal method in a generic class....in a non static class i use this. to refer to the object who call the equals, but in a static method how can i do?

```
> public static <T> boolean equals2(T object) {
        if (GenericClass == object) return true;
        if (object == null || GenericClass.class != object.getClass()) return false;
        GenericClass<?> that = (GenericClass<?>) object;
        return Objects.equals(object, that.t);
            }
```

I'm trying this but it gave me error on generic Class

Answer (score 0):

> public static  boolean equals2(T object) {

That method signature doesn't make sense because you only have 1 object so there isn't anything to compare it to.  If that needs to be a static method then it would make more sense to have the `equals2` method accept the 2 objects that you want to compare.  There are many utility methods that do this sort of thing.  One is https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object).

Comment: I solved, i create a static isEqual that take in input two object and call a non static equals

Answer (score -1):

The signature of the function should be different, you should get two objects
The first of type T
And the other of the object type.

Comment: "The first of type T And the other of the object type." - Why should one of them by of type `T`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).